# Multi Level Array - How to loop through and display 3rd level

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently working on communicating with the Expedia API. The response from Expedia API is a JSON array that is 4 levels deep. I can access the values with: eg. $data['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary']['0']['rateCurrencyCode'] - But there is multiple records for me to access and I am having trouble looping through the records to display a list of all the Hotel records. I have tried various different ways of looping the results but am completely stuck here and have not found any examples on how to loop through deeper levels in multi level arrays.

This is my response from API:

```
Array
(
    [HotelListResponse] => Array
        (
            [customerSessionId] => 0ABAAAD6-0372-E191-4CB2-719DEDD9325E
            [numberOfRoomsRequested] => 0
            [moreResultsAvailable] => 
            [HotelList] => Array
                (
                    [@size] => 232
                    [@activePropertyCount] => 232
                    [HotelSummary] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@order] => 0
                                    [hotelId] => 382498
                                    [name] => Georgetown Inn
                                    [address1] => 6100 Corson Avenue
                                    [city] => Seattle
                                    [stateProvinceCode] => WA
                                    [postalCode] => 98108
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                    [airportCode] => SEA
                                    [propertyCategory] => 1
                                    [hotelRating] => 2.5
                                    [confidenceRating] => 52
                                    [amenityMask] => 134234122
                                    [locationDescription] => Near Boeing Plant 2
                                    [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Georgetown Inn in Seattle, you'll be close to Boeing Plant 2 and Safeco Field. This hotel is within close proximity of Jefferson Park Golf Course and
                                    [highRate] => 80.25
                                    [lowRate] => 79.25
                                    [rateCurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [latitude] => 47.5478
                                    [longitude] => -122.32137
                                    [proximityDistance] => 11.007573
                                    [proximityUnit] => MI
                                    [hotelInDestination] => 1
                                    [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/5000000/4450000/4444400/4444333/4444333_86_t.jpg
                                    [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/484006/hotels/382498/overview?lang=en&currency=USD&standardCheckin=null/null/null&standardCheckout=null/null/null
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [@order] => 1
                                    [hotelId] => 125727
                                    [name] => Motif Seattle
                                    [address1] => 1415 5th Ave
                                    [city] => Seattle
                                    [stateProvinceCode] => WA
                                    [postalCode] => 98101
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                    [airportCode] => SEA
                                    [propertyCategory] => 1
                                    [hotelRating] => 4
                                    [confidenceRating] => 52
                                    [amenityMask] => 7798851
                                    [locationDescription] => Near Pike Place Market
                                    [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Motif Seattle, you'll be centrally located in Seattle, steps from 5th Avenue Theater and minutes from Pike Place Market. This 4-star hotel is within
                                    [highRate] => 339
                                    [lowRate] => 239
                                    [rateCurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [latitude] => 47.60985
                                    [longitude] => -122.33475
                                    [proximityDistance] => 11.168453
                                    [proximityUnit] => MI
                                    [hotelInDestination] => 1
                                    [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/1000000/60000/51000/50947/50947_264_t.jpg
                                    [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/484006/hotels/125727/overview?lang=en&currency=USD&standardCheckin=null/null/null&standardCheckout=null/null/null
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [@order] => 2
                                    [hotelId] => 164122
                                    [name] => The Westin Seattle
                                    [address1] => 1900 5th Ave
                                    [city] => Seattle
                                    [stateProvinceCode] => WA
                                    [postalCode] => 98101
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                    [airportCode] => SEA
                                    [propertyCategory] => 1
                                    [hotelRating] => 4
                                    [confidenceRating] => 5
                                    [amenityMask] => 7819587
                                    [locationDescription] => Near Pike Place Market
                                    [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at The Westin Seattle, you'll be centrally located in Seattle, steps from Westlake Center and minutes from Pacific Place. This 4-star hotel is close to
                                    [highRate] => 239
                                    [lowRate] => 189
                                    [rateCurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [latitude] => 47.61309
                                    [longitude] => -122.33788
                                    [proximityDistance] => 11.335604
                                    [proximityUnit] => MI
                                    [hotelInDestination] => 1
                                    [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/1000000/20000/16700/16673/16673_301_t.jpg
                                    [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/484006/hotels/164122/overview?lang=en&currency=USD&standardCheckin=null/null/null&standardCheckout=null/null/null
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [@order] => 3
                                    [hotelId] => 164116
                                    [name] => Sheraton Seattle Hotel
                                    [address1] => 1400 6th Ave
                                    [city] => Seattle
                                    [stateProvinceCode] => WA
                                    [postalCode] => 98101
                                    [countryCode] => US
                                    [airportCode] => SEA
                                    [propertyCategory] => 1
                                    [hotelRating] => 4
                                    [confidenceRating] => 30
                                    [amenityMask] => 278595
                                    [locationDescription] => Near Pike Place Market
                                    [shortDescription] => <p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Sheraton Seattle Hotel, you'll be centrally located in Seattle, steps from 5th Avenue Theater and Washington State Convention Center. This 4-star
                                    [highRate] => 450
                                    [lowRate] => 295
                                    [rateCurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [latitude] => 47.61017
                                    [longitude] => -122.33357
                                    [proximityDistance] => 11.115907
                                    [proximityUnit] => MI
                                    [hotelInDestination] => 1
                                    [thumbNailUrl] => /hotels/1000000/30000/25300/25290/25290_88_t.jpg
                                    [deepLink] => http://www.travelnow.com/templates/484006/hotels/164116/overview?lang=en&currency=USD&standardCheckin=null/null/null&standardCheckout=null/null/null
                                ) ......
```

I am trying to loop and display values from [0][1][2][3] levels in array. Could anyone help me with info on how to write the foreach loop?

Comment: try like this , foreach($yourarray as $a) { echo $a['@order']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foreach ($data['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary'] as $i=>$a) {
    echo $a['rateCurrencyCode'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stacks - that worked a charm !!!
I used it like this:

foreach ($data['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary'] as $a) { print_r($a['name']); }

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement recursive function:

```
function doLoop($foo) {
 if (is_array($foo)) {
   foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    doLoop($bar);
   }
 } else {
  /* do your staff with $foo */
 }
}

doLoop($foo);
```